# Why click function is triggering multiple times?

Tags: jquery

I've faced multiple times when I try to use `.click() function` that triggers the click event multiple times and have solved anyway previously and didn't noticed about this. And this time also I was facing the same problem and after an hour I noticed why this is happening. Below is an example:

**wrong:** (triggering click events multiple times)

```
$(selector).on('click',function(){
//do some func
}
$(another-selector).on('click',function(){
$(selector).click(); //trigger previous selector click function
}
```

**right:** (triggers once as expected)

```
$(another-selector).on('click',function(){
$(selector).click(); //trigger function before calling the function
}
$(selector).on('click',function(){
//do some func
}
```

Comment: What are `selector` and `another-selector`? Maybe `another-selector` is subset of `selector`?

Comment: And what are you actually asking?

Comment: @idlerboris yeah the `another-selector` is outside the `selector` markup

Answer (score 1):

You are missing ");" in some places

Here is how you should write it

```
$(selector).on('click',function(){
    //do some func
});
$(another-selector).on('click',function(){
    $(selector).click(); //trigger previous selector click function
});
```

Comment: @C-link Actually it is...

Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/BaXJ7/
The code is correct, but if you remove the two ); I added, it wont work. You are not closing your .on functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(selector).on('click',function(){
//do some func
}
$(another-selector).on('click',function(){
$(selector).trigger('click'); //trigger previous selector click function
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware of https://www.google.nl/search?q=event+propagation?

The issue could be anything, need some HTML and real selectors to answer this one...